# How to customize the name of task in apache flink dashboard?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to customize the name of a task in apache flink dashboard.

For example, when we have a task map in the dashboard the name is MAP, how can I change it to add a specific name?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Operators can be named using the `name()` method as shown in the following example:

```
DataStream<X> stream2 = stream
  .map(new MyMapper()).name("MyMapFunction")
  .map(new MyMapper2()).name("MyOtherMapper");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fabian

Comment: co-located operator subtasks render the taskname as concatenation. Do you know a way to control that?